# SQL Server 2012 backup path

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2012 database server which according to query output is being backed up once a week on Saturdays.  I thought a third-party tool was performing the backup, but found out it was not.  I do not know where these backup files are being written.  The physical device name from the query is as follows:

[image]

It is not a path, but looks like hex.  Can anyone clarify this output?

Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it is being backed up by CommVault.